# what are the practices to avoid a class becoming a god class?

Tags: class, refactoring

Let us take an example of a Consumer class. The functions related to a Consumer will go into this class. Gradually the Consumer class has lot of methods in it. And those are supposed to be part of the Consumer class itself. In such cases, how do we break it? are there any strategies related to solving this?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a broad question but I'll attempt to answer it.

[SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) are good practices to follow. If you apply these, especially the Single Responsibility Principle, you will end up with smaller classes with well defined responsibilities.

It's also important to look at [cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)) which is a measure of how related the elements of your class are. You want to aim for high cohesion in your classes (and modules). For example, if every method in your class uses a certain member variable, then cohesion is high. If there is a member variable of your class which is only used in one method, this is a good case to be refactored into a separate class.

Comment: the question here is : suppose there is a consumer class with lot of methods and those methods are related to the consumer - hence those methods should be part of the consumer class itself. In such a scenario how can the class be made simpler/better?

Comment: @user3760894 It really depends what those methods do. Do you have some specific examples?

Comment: I cannot share the code. Some examples are isActive(), isLongTermConsumer(), isPremiumCustomer(), hasDependents(), isOnboarded() etc..
If you look at the code and domain, they correspond to each other. But from a class perspective, it has too many methods.

Comment: @user3760894 These all seem to be properties of the Consumer. Do you have methods that correspond to these? For example, is there an Onboard() method that does the necessary on-boarding? If so, then these two are a good case for refactoring into another class. Also, do you have a matching isStandardCustomer() or similar which could be refactored to a "CustomerLevel" class with isPremiumCustomer(). It's quite difficult to talk about specifics without the full details. You have to think about whether these methods and properties belong together.

Comment: I get your point. But it may not represent the real world. For eg: we may not have a CustomerLevel entity in the real businessworld?

Comment: @user3760894 True but it kind of makes sense to me that if you have isPremiumCustomer() you would have the concept of a standard customer or similar. Together they represent a cohesive entity. What you call that depends on your context.

Answer (score 0):

Use structural design patterns. I would use either the Composite or Decorator design pattern to address your issue. You can learn about them here: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/structural_patterns

Comment: the question here is : suppose there is a consumer class with lot of methods and those methods are related to the consumer - hence those methods should be part of the consumer class itself. In such a scenario how can the class be made simpler/better?

Answer (score 0):

As already exposed by @MoonMoo the guidelines for refactoring a *fat* class should be SOLID principles and cohesion of classes.
The point is: ***even if a method is related to a Customer, should it stay in Customer class?
 Or that method can be called by the Customer from another class?***
The answer to these question could be a first starting point to understand which methods must stay in the Customer class and which methods can be relocated in another form in another class to which the Customer has a reference.